# 2d navigation robot setup dependency

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, create-autonomy, robot, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I am doing a 2d navigation and am using [`create_autonomy` for irobot](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy)

I am following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=linkto%3A%22navigation%2FTutorials%2FRobotSetup%22)

In it I need to create a package with dependency:

```
my_tf_configuration_dep
my_odom_configuration_dep
my_sensor_configuration_dep
```

if I am using `create_autonomy` package and `urg_node` package do I still need to create those dependency? If so how?

Update:

I created move_base with dependency of move_base urg_node and ca_driver.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324904/2d-navigation-robot-setup-dependency/) by [Usui](https://answers.ros.org/users/36306/usui/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2019-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe what you need is an equivalent of `my_tf_configuration_dep`.

`create_autonomy` (specifically, `ca_driver`) provides odometry on a topic and the transform from the odometry frame to the base frame on `/tf`. And `urg_node` is providing sensor data.

Specifically, I think you need to provide the transform from your robot base to your range finder. There are a few ways you could do this. Assuming that your range finder will not be moving with respect to the robot base, you could use a [static transform publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_ros#static_transform_publisher). For example:

```
rosrun tf2_ros static_transform_publisher X Y Z YAW PITCH ROLL base_footprint laser
```

I'm assuming that the robot base and range finder frames are `base_footprint` and `laser`, but these are configurable in `create_autonomy` and `urg_node` respectively. You should replace `X Y Z YAW PITCH ROLL` with the actual transformation from `base_footprint` to `laser`.

Launch file equivalent:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser_broadcaster"
             args="X Y Z YAW PITCH ROLL base_footprint laser" />
</launch>
```

Other options are to describe your robot configuration with URDF and publish the transform using [robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) ([tutorial1](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher),  [tutorial2](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher/Tutorials/Using%20the%20robot%20state%20publisher%20on%20your%20own%20robot)) or, publish the laser transform from code ([tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF)).

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2019-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Usui](https://answers.ros.org/users/36306/usui/) on 2019-06-06**:
oh you mean this: rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser 100?
I have this already so I just need to configs and launch file then?

So then I just need to do: catkin_create_pkg my_robot_name_2dnav move_base

instead of catkin_create_pkg my_robot_name_2dnav move_base my_tf_configuration_dep my_odom_configuration_dep my_sensor_configuration_dep ?

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2019-06-06**:
That sounds about right to me. Maybe you can replace the "my_configuration_*" dependencies with the actual packages you are depending on e.g. `ca_driver` and `urg_node`.

**Comment by [Usui](https://answers.ros.org/users/36306/usui/) on 2019-06-06**:
Okay I will try that. Oh and I don't need the robot_configuration launch file right? just the move_base launch file

**Comment by [Usui](https://answers.ros.org/users/36306/usui/) on 2019-06-09**:
@jacobperron I updated my progress. Now it just spins alot. Here's a link to it: http://answers.ros.org/question/325237/2d-navigation-goal-robot-spinning-even-when-disconnected/